# How to call one controller array in another controller

Tags: angularjs

I have created countryApp  module. I have created "names" array in aboutCtrl.

I want to access "names" array in contactCtrl in insertContact function.

```
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', ['ngRoute']);

  countryApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        template: '<h1>Home</h1>',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }).

      when('/aboutus', {
        templateUrl: 'aboutus.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
      }).

      when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'cotacts.html',
        controller: 'contactCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });

countryApp.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

});

countryApp.controller('aboutCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.names = [{name:'venu',number:'22222',sex:'male'},{name:'Aishu',number:'1111',sex:'female'},{name:'Milky',number:'2222',sex:'female'}]




});

countryApp.controller('contactCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';                                    
      $scope.insertContact = function () {



         alert(names);

     }
     $scope.resetContact = function () {

     }
});
```

Comment: short answer is, you can't access them directly;  you'll need to create a service to hold any data you want to access from more than one controller, unless the controllers are nested in the HTML, which they don't appear to be in this case.

Comment: I agree with @Claies . Wrap the array in a service and inject it into your controllers

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Claies' solution with actual code:

```
countryApp.controller('aboutCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

    /* If you're binding the values into your HTML,
    you need to $watch the service variable 'names' */

    $scope.$watch(function() { return dataService.names }, function() {
        $scope.names = dataService.names;
    });

    dataService.names = [{name:'venu',number:'22222',sex:'male'},{name:'Aishu',number:'1111',sex:'female'},{name:'Milky',number:'2222',sex:'female'}]

});

countryApp.controller('contactCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

    /* You can place the same watch as in aboutCtrl here if
    you're displaying stuff in HTML that's related to this controller */

        $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
      $scope.insertContact = function () {

         alert(dataService.names);

     }
     $scope.resetContact = function () {

     }
});

countryApp.service('dataService', function() {
    var dataObj = {};

    dataobj.names = [];

    return dataObj;
});
```

Do notice the comments about `$watch`ing the service variable; if you want to display the values in the view through a `$scope` variable, you'll need to `$watch` the corresponding service variable or the `$scope` variable won't be updated when the value of the service variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate between two controllers, then please take reference of the following fiddle:

`Fiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/VaibhavP17/nky45/

It shows how to communicate between the two controllers and also the nuances of events. I hope this helps :)